# VPS IP address for local site

Tags: 14.04, networking, apache2, vps

I have no experience in about Apache and want to set up `Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` for a local site on my `local machine`. I followed [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts). But when I try to test `http://example.com` I got this result in browser:

```
 Example Domain

 This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in
 documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior
 coordination or asking for permission.

 More information...
```

And I expected to get `Success!  The example.com virtual host is working!` as result (as described in followed tutorial).

In that tutorial, I did not understand:

```
 For the domains that I used in this guide, assuming that my VPS IP
 address is 111.111.111.111, I could add the following lines to the
 bottom of my hosts file
```

So I used `111.111.111.111` in `/etc/hosts` and I guess problem is in about that, but I searched in google and did not find any thing about how to get 
my `VPS IP address` to use that. Now how I can get that address or I make mistake and I have to set an address and then use it? In second case how can I do that?

Comment: You need to change "111.111.111.111" to your actual ip address and "example.com" to your actual server name.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think `example.com` is actual server name. But does changing to actual IP Address cause any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Step Six — Set Up Local Hosts File (Optional)**
>
> If you haven't been using actual domain names that you own to test
>   this procedure and have been using some example domains instead, you
>   can at least test the functionality of this process by temporarily
>   modifying the hosts file on your local computer.
>
> This will intercept any requests for the domains that you configured
>   and point them to your VPS server, just as the DNS system would do if
>   you were using registered domains. This will only work from your
>   computer though, and is simply useful for testing purposes.
>
> Make sure you are operating on your local computer for these steps and
>   not your VPS server. You will need to know the computer's
>   administrative password or otherwise be a member of the administrative
>   group.
>
> If you are on a Mac or Linux computer, edit your local file with
>   administrative privileges by typing:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/hosts
> ```

He is clearly talking about a second machine not the VPS server. Because if those domains are not yours, you can't have a public DNS to point them to your VPS server. So you can go the other way and trick your second machine using `hosts` files.

1. In your VPS server, run `ifconfig` to get its public IP.
2. In you second machine, edit `/etc/hosts` file and add the below line with that IP:

   ```
   vps-server-ip example.com
   vps-server-ip test.com
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this doubt while following the instructions on this page. I used my internal IP address and the `ServerName` that I set on the .conf file created and it worked.

In my case before I added this to `/etc/hosts` the browser displayed "DNS address could not be found." as my `ServerName` domain didn't existed. In your case, [example.com](http://example.com/) is an real domain. That page with "This domain is established to be used for illustrative..." is the actual page. It is not a message related to something you did while configuring your Apache. You can access this page from any device.

You can find your IP by right-clicking on the network icon and selecting Connection Information. The item IP Address on IPv4 shows you your internal IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the problem you had. I've done a simple change and I could get the expected result "Success!  The example.com virtual host is working!".

type

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts"
```

in your terminal.

You have to enter your IP address instead of `111.111.111.111`

To get the IP address type

```
ifconfig
```

in terminal.

There you can see

```
inet addr:127.0.0.1  in lo section.
```